# Client doesn't receive message from Server - using select() call on server

Tags: java, sockets, select, network-programming, serversocket

My regular TCP client working great with regular TCP server but not SelectServer that is basically a TCP server using select() call for non-blocking IO :

```
class TCPClient { 

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception 
{ 
    if (args.length != 2)
    {
        System.out.println("Usage: TCPClient <Server IP> <Server Port>");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    // Initialize a client socket connection to the server
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1])); 

    // Initialize input and an output stream for the connection(s)
    DataOutputStream outBuffer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream()); 
    BufferedReader inBuffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream())); 

    // Initialize user input stream
    String line; 
    BufferedReader inFromUser = 
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 

    // Get user input and send to the server
    // Display the echo meesage from the server
    System.out.print("Please enter a message to be sent to the server ('logout' to terminate): ");
    line = inFromUser.readLine(); 
    while (!line.equals("logout") )
    {
        try{
        // Send to the server
        outBuffer.writeBytes(line + '\n'); 

        // Getting response from the server
        System.out.println("Bytes written.. waiting for response");
        line = inBuffer.readLine();
        System.out.println("Message received!");
        System.out.println("Server: " + line);
        }catch(SocketException e){}
        System.out.print("Please enter a message to be sent to the server ('logout' to terminate): ");
        line = inFromUser.readLine(); 
    }


    // Close the socket
    clientSocket.close();           
}
```

}

This TCP client gets stuck on line `line = inBuffer.readLine();` as it didn't receive any message.

My server using select() call for non-blocking IO:

```
    public class SelectServer {

   public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
      //InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("some host or ip"); //Enter some host or ip here 

      Selector selector = Selector.open();

      ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
      serverSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
      InetSocketAddress isa1 = new InetSocketAddress(9000);
      serverSocketChannel.socket().bind(isa1);
      serverSocketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);


      while (true) {

         if (selector.select(500) < 0) //500miliseconds
                {
                    System.out.println("select() failed");
                    System.exit(1);
                }

         Set selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
         Iterator iterator = selectedKeys.iterator();

         while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) iterator.next();
            iterator.remove();

            if (key.isAcceptable()) {
               //System.out.println("Acceptable");
               SocketChannel sc = serverSocketChannel.accept();
               sc.configureBlocking(false);
               sc.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
               System.out.println("Connection Accepted: " + sc.getLocalAddress() + "\n");
            }

            if (key.isReadable()) {
                //System.out.println("Readable");
               SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
               ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
               int bytesRead = sc.read(bb);
               String result = new String(bb.array()).trim();
               System.out.println("Message received: " + result + " ,Message length= " + result.length());

               if (result.equals("logout")) {
                  sc.close();
                  System.out.println("Connection closed...");
                  System.out.println("Server will keep running. " +"Try running another client to " + "re-establish connection");
               }

               sc.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);

            }  
            if (key.isWritable()){

                System.out.println("Writable");                   

                SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
                ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap("text".getBytes());

                int bytesWritten = sc.write(bb);
                System.out.println(bytesWritten);  //Prints 4 

                bb.rewind();

                sc.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);

            }

         }
      }
   }
}
```

In line `int bytesWritten = sc.write(bb);` , bytes written print 4. So bytes were sent..but not received. The client is stuck in the line I provided above.

If i don't "mess with" the ByteBuffer, and just echo the message, it gets send perfectly. However if I actually try to input custom message into ByteBuffer, the client doen't receive it.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding a new line to the end solved the issue like so, "text\n". Can't believe it was that simple.